# My app store is not working!

Tags: ios-appstore

I think it is because of the apple 9.0.2 update. When I try to dowload a app it makes a loading sign, but then it says get. Then I click it and it loads and then says get. I have read answers and tried them, but they do not work! What should I do? I do not want to restart my device!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple Support System Status](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/), now, the iTunes Store
Service may be unavailable for some users.